# Powershell how to parse array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a microsoft form that submits an array of data to a variable that I need to process.
The Output array from the forms looks like this and is assigned to a variable:

```
["a","b","c"]
```

How can I create an array in powershell from this so I can actually call the array items like this:

```
if ("a" in $array) {
     # Do something
}

if ("b" in $array) {
     # Do something
}

if ("c" in $array) {
     # Do something
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output from your form, by the looks of it, is a JSON string which you can convert to an object using [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.2):

```bash
$var = '["a","b","c"]'
$array = $var | ConvertFrom-Json

switch($array) {
    a { 'a in array'; continue }
    b { 'b in array'; continue }
    c { 'c in array'; continue }
    Default { 'nothing found' }
}
```

**Note**, the use of the `continue` on above example is strictly for efficiency. From [about_Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) documentation we can read the following:

> The `Break` keyword stops processing and exits the Switch statement.
> The `Continue` keyword stops processing the current value, but continues processing any subsequent values.